# about Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

Can someone help me with this:

How to write a UNIX shell script that takes a parameter. The parameter passed should be the name of a file that is executable. Validate the parameter and if it is not valid output an appropriate error message and ensure your script exits with an overall status of error. If the parameter is valid execute the parameter. If the execution of the parameter fails then output an appropriate error message and ensure your script exits with an overall status of error. If the parameter is valid and executed successfully my script should exit with an overall status of success.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that's not a prob.

Split your task into 4 simple steps:

1. How to pass command line arguments to bash script.
2. How to check whether executable file exists.
3. How to display message in bash.
4. How to execute something from bash.

You'r welcome!

Comment: Thanks. I am new to unix and wanted to know how to write in a scripting language. Please help me with that.

Comment: @Bruce I apologize but it looks like you're asking to do homework for you, it isn't a good idea to use stackoverflow for that. If you search (google) and complete each step yourself, you will get your script easily.